# How to show the current date and time at the third results of false condition value

Tags: javascript, datetime, boolean

I want to show the current date and time at the third results of false condition value.

Here is the code :

```js
const lists = [
  {
    name: 'peter',
    value: false,
    datetime: (new Date().toString())
  },
]

const showData = () => {
  const array = [];

  const object = {
    name2: lists[0].name,
    value2: lists[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5,
    datetime2: lists[0].datetime
  }
  array.push(object);

  const datetime3 = (new Date().toString());
  array.reduce((acc, x) => {
    if(!x.value2) return acc.concat(x);
    x.datetime2 = datetime3;
    return acc.concat(x);
  },[])
  console.log(array);
}

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);

const stopToSee = setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 5000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If we try to run the code above, we can see if the `value2` past 3 conditions (false -> true -> false). Datetime at the first false condition is equal with datetime at the third false condition.

Result above is not always same because the code generate random true or false value, you can see the `value2` result pass 3 conditions below.

Example code result :

```
// first false condition, time shown 00:00:00
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// second true condition
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:02 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:03 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// third false condition, time shown 00:00:00 same with the first false condition
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
```

Result i expected :

```
// first false condition, time shown 00:00:00
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// second true condition
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:02 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": true,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:03 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]

// third false condition, time shown 00:00:04 this is the result i expected
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:04 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
[
  {
    "name2": "peter",
    "value2": false,
    "datetime2": "Sun Mar 19 2018 00:00:04 GMT+0700 (WIB)"
  }
]
```

How to make datetime at the first false condition different with the third false condition, like the result i expected above. I mean, the third false condition show the current datetime at the third false condition, not the first false condition datetime.

Note : I really need to create new `object` in `showData` which will continuously show the data every 1 second, because in the real code (long enough to display here) i used promise function to generate new value. So after the new value is generated, i must create new object with the new value inside it.

I really hope someone can help me.

**Added another list :**

```js
const lists = [
  {
    name: 'peter',
    value: false,
    datetime: (new Date().toString())
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    value: false,
    datetime: (new Date().toString())
  }
]

const showData = () => {
  const array = [];

  for (let x = 0; x < lists.length; x++) {
    const object = {
      name2: lists[x].name,
      value2: lists[x].value = Math.random() >= 0.5,
      datetime2: lists[x].datetime
    }
    array.push(object);
  }

  const datetime3 = (new Date().toString());
  array.reduce((acc, x) => {
    if(!x.value2) return acc.concat(x);
    x.datetime2 = datetime3;
    return acc.concat(x);
  },[])
  console.log(array);
}

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);

const stopToSee = setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 5000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: based on your result vs expected it sounds like you need to create a new date time whenever a false condition is it.

Comment: @Jhecht thank you very much for your answer, but how to do that? i'm really new and i hope you can show me the code.

Comment: without knowing why you are doing what you are doing, it's hard to help. your code appears to be _really_ redundant and I can't process why you are doing things the way you are. From what I think you are trying to do, you are trying to set a timed log of true/false conditions, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. i trying to set a timed log of true/false conditions. but the code i shown above is not show the current datetime at the third results of false condition value like result i expected above.

Comment: @Jhecht i'm sorry for my code appears to be really redundant, i already updated my code and just show for the 5 results. if you run the snippet code, the result is not always same because the code generate random true or false value, you can see the `value2` result pass 3 conditions at 'Example code result'

Answer (score 0):

Given our quick chat in the comments, I *think* this is more along the lines of what you want.

### Some Quick Talking Points

1. not everything needs to be a constant in Javascript. I'm unaware if you knew this, but there is also the `var`, which the older/original variable declaration that has a different sort of scoping than the newer counterpart, `let`. You may want to read up a little bit about those 3 things.
2. In your original code you were using some redundant work, such as creating a new array with only 1 element, and then calling the `.reduce()` method on that newly created array to do... something. Please note that `.reduce()` is used for taking an array and reducing it down from it's current structure to a different one. If you want to keep the code as you had it, look into `.map()` or `.forEach()`. Last benchmark I saw said that `.map` was faster, especially on larger data sets.
3. I believe you were calling `.concat()` in order to append the array values from your original `lists` array -- how you were doing that simply would not have worked.
4. I have used an Object function [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). It creates a ***new*** object based on the first passed object, and merges the properties of any other object passed to it. The reason we want a new object, rather than a flat duplicate of the old one, is that any changes made to `lists[0]` will be reflected in the other changes *unless* we make a new object.
5. `Array.push()` Adds whatever you pass as the argument as the *last* item in the array. i.e. `[1,2].push(3)` turns into `[1,2,3]`. `Array.unshift()` does much the same task, except for the value is added to the *beginning* of the array, e.g. `[1,2].unshift(3)` will result in `[3,1,2]`

Let me know if you have any questions about what I've done.

#### for clarity on point #4:

```
let obj1 = {a:1,b:2};
let obj2 = obj1;
obj1.a=3;
console.log(obj1.a, obj2.a); //Will output 3 for both
// whereas 
let obj1 = {a:1,b:2};
let obj2 = Object.assign(obj1, {a:5});
console.log(obj1.a, obj2.a); // output: 1 5
```

```js
const lists = [
  {
    name: 'peter',
    value: false,
    datetime: (new Date().toString())
  },
];

const showData = () => {
  let obj = 
    Object.assign({},lists[0], {
      value:  Math.random() > 0.5,
      datetime : new Date().toString()
    });
  lists.push(obj);
  console.log(lists);
  
};

const interval = setInterval(showData, 1000);

const stopToSee = setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 5000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the real use, i have another list data to process but in this question i just add one list (just for make it simple to understand) but i already updated and add another list at code above.

Comment: Is the code in your answer the _exact_ code (removing any secure / site specific information)?

Comment: Also, what is this code supposed to accomplish exactly? I'm not seeing a use for setting a true/false value randomly ever second

Comment: I think my code is not related to removing any secure or site specific information. I just doing this code on my own site and create a random boolean value that can show the current datetime at the third result of false condition like the example above.

Comment: Yes, you've said that before, and I am still not understanding what functionality you are aiming for. _What does this code accomplish?_ If it does not serve a purpose, are you making this only to learn how to make it? If so, it seems weird to learn how to make this out of all things you could've worked on

Comment: Ok, the real functionality of this code is for make the list data like `name` represent to `host`, `value` represent to `latency`(is ping value in milliseconds) and datetime represent the time when the host is up or down accordingly the latency result reply or timeout. If the result host of latency down/timeout, i want the date show the current datetime at the third result of timeout condition. I make the example code above because in my real code i used child_process to run the ping command from my operating system that imposible to run with code snippet in this post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167062/discussion-between-jhecht-and-ras).